# What does this D3D11 INFO line in my output mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

I get the following line in my Visual Studio output when I close my win32 DirectX application:

```
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11ClassLinkage: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00893E04 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097295: DESTROY_CLASSLINKAGE]
```

What does this mean? Can this output be avoided? and should it be?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of Direct3D's SDK Debug Layer.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/04/15/object-naming.aspx) blog post for more info.